# Pygame application doesn't close out the first time

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a small game in pygame and I wanted a function to exit out. However it takes multiple clicks to exit and it is not consistent either. Also the windows exit function is restarting the program, too Here is the part of the code that deals with exiting

```
    if isKill:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gameover = myfont.render("Press R to Respawn", False, (255, 255, 255))
        rect = gameover.get_rect()
        rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
        screen.blit(gameover, rect)
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_r:
                gameloop()
```

and

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
```

*gameloop() is the whole script

Comment: Are you calling `gameloop()` from within `gameloop()` ?

Comment: Yes, im calling it within gameloop()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `event.type`, you can use the pygame builtin event `QUIT`

Refer the following code

```
running = True
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        #Can use pygame.quit() in place of running=False if the above line doesn't work.
```

This `while` loop is the starting of gameloop. The contents of the gameloop should be inside it.
**Don't** call the `gameloop()` function inside the while loop

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use `sys.exit` to stop the program.
Try:

```
import sys
import pygame

while 1:

    #code

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your game loop, you should always keep the loop running at one level. In your code, the respawn actually freezes the current level and reruns the game at a lower level. This is why several quit commands are required to exit the game.

When the player respawns, reset the game variables, then continue the game loop.

Update your code similar to this:

```
if isKill:  # game is over
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameover = myfont.render("Press R to Respawn", False, (255, 255, 255))
    rect = gameover.get_rect()
    rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    screen.blit(gameover, rect)
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_r:
            #gameloop() # remove this
            dospawn()  # initialize\reset game variables here (can use same function at game start)
            isKill = False  # start new game
    continue  # skip rest of game process
```